# How to save the order in the rearranged uitable view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have come across this situation that after user has tapped on edit and the table turns into editing mode then user moves one of the rows.

So my question is :currently the source array comes from web service so
 after moving the rows where to store the rearrangement i.e.
 rank that the user has given so next time the user comes back to the tab or 
relaunches the app the user gets the same reordered rows as the user has done before

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thre are few options you can do, one would be to have your webservice return enumerated entries, and store the new orders in the users device (to a file maybe), now when the user comes back, you should be able to use the stored enumeration to switch around the entries that came from  the webservice and there you go... there are other options such as caching the data to the phone (if its static and not a huge size), or storing the users order  in the server (though you probably dont want to do that). Hope this helps

Comment: should I save the whole indexPath for the table before switching the view or terminating the app and use it when the app launches again.